# Unity Container with Composition Root

Tags: c#, design-patterns, unity-container

I am new to DI and unity container. I am trying to use Unity with Composition Root. I have all my unity mappings/registrations in app.config file and just want to centralise all the resolve calls for my application.

The Application has many classes and very nested object graph created using constructor injection. So in a centralise location I want to create this object graph and then start make the call to do the actual work.

Please suggest a good way to implement composition root with unity.

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of application are you working on? Different application types have different _ideal_ composition root locations.

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest you a principle of composition root. 
Composition root is an application infrastructure component so only application should have it and it is the unique location where modules are composed together.

Moreover, It depends on your application that you are developing.
For instance:
- Console application . It's main method.
- ASP.NET MVC application. It's global.asax

So no matter what is DI container. you can easily organize Composition root if you understand the principle behind that.

I'm not using Unity but I think, It's not much different with others

Hope it helps for you.

Comment: Thanks! for the reply, My app is a batch process. After reading many views including yours I am feeling to create a dedicated static class to build the object graph. Somewhat like this http://blog.anthonybaker.me/2011/02/factory-pattern-using-unity-application.html